# How to generate query-dsl Q classes on external entity?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, querydsl

I make use of an `@Entity` class from a commons library:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String firstname;
    
    @NotNull
    private String lastname;
}
```

In my impl application, I want to generated a `QPerson` querydsl entity. But how? Because I have no control over the commons library, I cannot simply add the `@QueryEntity` annotation for the querydsl processor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution. Yet I don't know if that's the correct way, so would be still happy for your comments.

Create a `package-info` somewhere in the implementation project as follows:

```
@QueryEntities(value = {Person.class})
package my.impl.project
```

What is strange: now all of the entity classes from the commons project get generated. Therefore I restricted the path in maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${apt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                <options>        
                    <querydsl.includedPackages>org.common.domain.person</querydsl.includedPackages>
                </options>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: In my case, I didn't need the <options> tag. The package-info worked by its own and the plugin generated a Query entity only for the desired entity.
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Many thank's. It helped me too! Options section is not need to add in my case

Answer (score -1):

In our project, we didn't like the fact that some source code was generated. So, we disabled code generation and write our Q files for Query dsl manually. We looked at generated files and just write them the same way as they would be generated. Remember though that your Q file MUST be in the same package as your entity file for which it is written

Comment: Well but that's impossible as I depend on an external commons library's @Entity, so I cannot add a q-file there

Comment: Of course, it is possible. You can create the same package in your project as the package where your 3d-party entity sits and put your Q- files there.

Comment: I don't think the same package would be required. In fact, the package name can be prefixed by the configuration options. Isn't there something else causing issues in your situation, like package protected class visibility? It is true that the metamodel can quite easily be maintained without the codegen tools.