# How to generate Query classes when an entity extends a class from an external package that does not have support for QueryDsl?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am having an entity class like below:

`public class Apple extends ExternalClass implements Serializable {}`

Here `Apple` is extending a class `ExternalClass` which is a part of a external package(not part of project source code).

When I am trying to use mvn compile, the compilation is failing with an error

> error: cannot find symbol 
> symbol:   class QExternalClass 
> location: package com.example.models 
> public final com.example.models.ExternalClass _super = new com.example.models.ExternalClass(this);

One solution that I can think of is to add QueryDsl to the external package, and then importing it. Is there any other solution available for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is by adding `@QueryEntities(value = {ExternalClass.class})` to `package-info`.

For more details check [How to generate query-dsl Q classes on external entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65111043/how-to-generate-query-dsl-q-classes-on-external-entity)